# Understanding this pattern: videojs("videoPlayer", {}, function(){}

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm a recent refugee from planet Flex/Actionscript and am still figuring out the basics so this is probably a pretty simple question. I am confused by the line below:

```
videojs("videoPlayer", {}, function(){}
```

Although I am using it successfully (below) I don't fully understand it. It seems to be directing a global `videojs` object to find an instance of id "videoPlayer", with optional params (the {} ) and then call the anonymous function on the instance.

Do I have that right? What triggered my confusion is the optional params (the {} ). Could I use that to pass in the `src` and `poster` and skip the function? Does this pattern have a name and is it common?

Feel free to yell at me if this is a duplicate...

---

**Context:** I am building a desktop app using `Electron` to host `Timeline.js` in which I access and display local .mp4 files. `Timeline.js` uses an `iFrame` as an "include anything you want" option, so I have a "video.html" file as the source for the iFrame. In the JSON for the timeline, I use a query string to pass params to the iFrame for `Video.js`

---

```
<script>
    function getParamValue(paramName) {
        var url = window.location.search.substring(1); 
        var qArray = url.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
            var pArr = qArray[i].split('=');
            if (pArr[0] == paramName)
                return pArr[1];
        }
    }

    // grap the video & poster frame refs from url
    var videoSrc = getParamValue('videoSrc');
    videoSrc = "assets/videos/" + videoSrc;

    var poster = getParamValue('poster');
    poster = "assets/images/" + poster;

    videojs("videoPlayer", {}, function(){
           this.src(videoSrc);
           this.poster(poster);
           this.load();
    });

</script>
```

---

Snippet from my Timeline.js JSON

```
"media": {
        "caption": "caption",
        "credit": "",
        "url": "<iframe allowfullscreen 
                        webkitallowfullscreen
                        src='video.html?videoSrc=Z.mp4&poster=W.jpg'
                        width='320' height='240'></iframe>", 
         },
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be explained in the Video.js documentation?

Comment: @JJJ my question extends beyond `Video.js` to understanding the specifics of the code, not the API alone.

Comment: This is not much a pattern. videojs is a function. Somebody has written it and you simply call it with 3 parameters — a string, an empty object literal, and a function. What is accepted in param 2 — this is a question for VideoJS docs. Hope this is not too basic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all down to the videojs implementation.

The [second {} parameter](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/options.html) is an 'empty object', but lets you pass in extra parameters if you want.

The [third parameter](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html) (where you have the anonymous function) is a function to run after videojs has loaded and initialised.

This is all explained in the video js documentation, but as you are a javascript newbie I'm being forgiving, as both 'an empty object {}' may be new concept to you, as might be the fact that javascript files take time to load asynchronously, and then of course their code takes time to initialise, so it is common in good 3rd-party libraries to implement 'run this code when initialised' behaviour, by passing in a function.

So, yes, this is a fairly common implementation 'pattern' for initialising 3rd-party javascript libraries, but I don't believe it has a specific name.

Comment: thanks – that's what I needed to know. It is all quite different from class-based Actionscript so these global functions, etc. are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the second parameter to replace the "ready function" of the third parameter, example:

```
videojs("videoPlayer", { src: videoSrc, poster: videoPoster, preload: true } });
```

And the player is ready!

Just a simple tip:

You can write the video source using these methods:

```
src: "http://www.example.com/path/to/video.mp4"
```

or

```
src: { type: "video/mp4", src: "http://www.example.com/path/to/video.mp4" }
```

or

```
src: [
  { type: "video/mp4", src: "http://www.example.com/path/to/video.mp4" },
  { type: "video/webm", src: "http://www.example.com/path/to/video.webm" },
  { type: "video/ogg", src: "http://www.example.com/path/to/video.ogv" }
]
```

The second one makes the things easy for the videojs engine check if it has support to play that file.

The last one gives a chance for the player plays an alternative file type if its browser has no support for the file, in that order.

Good luck and happy play :-)